# converting hsl to rgb in python3

Tags: python-3.x, color-space, hsl

I have a numpy array-an 2D numpy array of [H, S, L] for each pixel-and I want to convert these into rgb variables. There wasn't a hsl-rgb converter in matplotlib.colors and I couldn't find a converter that uses arrays as a input. So I had to make it myself.
I found a conversion equation [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsl-to-rgb.html).
Everything was okay except that I got stuck implementing the if's.

Can I get help either making the if's statement or finding a function that converts a rsl array to rgb array?

Here's my conversion function I currently made.

```
def hsl2rgb(self,H,S,L):
    C = np.multiply(1-np.abs(2*L-1),S)
    X = np.multply(C, 1 - np.abs(np.mod(H*6,2)-1))
    m = np.subtract(L, C/2)
    h=np.floor(6*H)
```

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: OK. I'm outside now, so I'll edit it as soon as I go home

Answer (score -1):

Hasel provides rsl-to-rgb conversion for array type datas.